# android and sqlite difficulties

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android and Sq-lite and I cannot seem to get this database class to work. On the home screen you select a country, it then moves to the data screen and displays that data for the corresponding country, but I cannot seen to load the database it produces the following errors in logCat, please let me know if you need more details, any help would be great:

```
06-12 19:44:59.893: E/Trace(1215): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-12 19:45:00.923: I/Choreographer(1215): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 19:45:01.003: D/gralloc_goldfish(1215): Emulator without GPU emulation det`enter code here`ected.
06-12 19:45:03.803: D/AndroidRuntime(1215): Shutting down VM
06-12 19:45:03.803: W/dalvikvm(1215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.populateTable(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:43)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.onCreate(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:37)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.findCountry(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:341)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.HomeScreen$1.onClick(HomeScreen.java:38)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my class:

```
package com.Jamie.dosanddonts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DosAndDontsDbAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "dosAndDonts";
    private static final String COUNTRY = "Country name";
    private static final String INDICATOR = "Indicator";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    private TextView temp;
    private Country currentCountry; 

    public DosAndDontsDbAdapter(Context context) {
          super(context, DATABASE_TABLE, null,DATABASE_VERSION); 
          }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + COUNTRY + " TEXT," + INDICATOR + " TEXT,"
                + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT" + ")"; 

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        populateTable();
    }

        public void populateTable()
        {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Shake hands when you greet someone.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do say 'bonjour' or 'bonsoir'.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Flowers should be given in odd numbers but not 13.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always smile");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always arrive on time for dinner.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating Do not rest your elbows on the table.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Don't refer to someone by their first name unless you are a close friend.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never offer cheap wine.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not begin eating until the hostess says 'bon appetit' ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not cut salad with a knife and fork. Fold the lettuce on to your fork. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();


        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Shake hands when greeting and leaving someone.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When you have finished eating lay your knide and fork parallel across your plate.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When in a pub pay for a round of drinks for everyone in your group.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating The fork is held tines down so food is scooped on to the back of the fork.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating, Table manners are Continental.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never get in their personal space.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "It's inapropriate to ask personal questions.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "They'll become unconfortalbe if engage in prolonged eye contact.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating don't rest your elbows on the table.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "DON'T make the V for victory sign with your palm facing yourself.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();


        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When greeting The usual handshake with direct eye contact.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Have calling card made.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you bring wine, make sure it is a good vintage.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you are invited to a meal, bring gift-wrapped such as wine or chocolates. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Table manners are Continental.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never give your business card in lieu of a calling card in a social situation.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give chrysanthemums as they are used at funerals.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not keep your hands in your lap during the meal.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give red flowers as they indicate secrecy. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give yellow flowers as they indicate jealousy.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "A quick, firm handshake is the traditional greeting.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Titles are very important and denote respect.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When entering a room, shake hands with everyone individually.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Yellow roses or tea roses are always well received. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you bring wine, it should be imported.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give lilies or chrysanthemums as they are used at funerals. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never arrive early, aslways on time.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not begin eating until the hostess starts.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not rest your elbows on the table.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not cut lettuce in a salad. Fold it using your knife and fork.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();


        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Many men use a two-handed shake.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always bring a gift to someones house.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always keep your hands visible when eating.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Use utensils to eat most food.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you have not finished eating, cross your knife and fork on your plate.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not begin eating until the hostess starts.  ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not get up until the guest of honour does. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never toast first always allow the host to.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When at dinner don't sit unless invited to do so.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Don't go bare cheasted anywhere other than the beach or poolside.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     public void findCountry(String country)
       {
        int index = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        List <DosAndDonts> dosNDonts = new ArrayList <DosAndDonts>();

        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {INDICATOR, DESCRIPTION }, COUNTRY + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(country) }, null, null, null, null);

        Country returnedCountry = new Country();
        returnedCountry.setName(country);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            dosNDonts.add(new DosAndDonts(cursor.getString(index),
                        cursor.getString(index + 1)));          

            index = index + 2;          
        }

        returnedCountry.setCountryDosAndDonts(dosNDonts);

        currentCountry = returnedCountry;
        this.displayResult();
       }

        public void displayResult() 
        {

            TextView country = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Country_name);
            TextView do1 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do1);
            TextView do2 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do2);
            TextView do3 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do3);
            TextView do4 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do4);
            TextView do5 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do5);
            TextView dont1 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont1);
            TextView dont2 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont2);
            TextView dont3 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont3);
            TextView dont4 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont4);
            TextView dont5 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont5);

            TextView dos[] = { do1, do2, do3, do4, do5 };
            TextView donts[] = { dont1, dont2, dont3, dont4, dont5 };

            int doCounter = 0;
            int dontCounter = 0;
            int index = 0;
            List <DosAndDonts> dosNDonts = currentCountry.getCountryDosAndDonts(); 

            country.setText(currentCountry.getName());

            while (index < dosNDonts.size())
            {
                if (dosNDonts.get(index).getIndicator().equals("Do"))
                {
                    dos[doCounter].setText(dosNDonts.get(index).getDescription());
                    doCounter++;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    donts[dontCounter].setText(dosNDonts.get(index).getDescription());
                    dontCounter++;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }




     }
```

Hi thanks for your response, I have made the changes on the onCreate() and populate() methods and now get this set of error messages in my logCat starting from (1) and the set of messages repeats itself about 50 times, again any help would be great.

```
06-12 19:53:00.803: I/Choreographer(1549): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 19:53:00.873: D/gralloc_goldfish(1549): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-12 19:53:04.593: E/SQLiteLog(1549): (1) near "name": syntax error
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549): Error inserting Country name=France     Description=Shake hands when you greet someone. Indicator=Do
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO dosAndDonts(Country name,Description,Indicator) VALUES (?,?,?)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.populateTable(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:49)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.onCreate(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:37)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.findCountry(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:341)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.HomeScreen$1.onClick(HomeScreen.java:38)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-12 19:53:04.653: E/SQLiteDatabase(1549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have called `getDatabase` in a recusive loop.. . (ah its all in one box

Comment: here is the error `06-12 19:45:03.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.populateTable(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:43)` in your `DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java line number 43`.

Comment: Just curious, does populateTable() need to be public?  Is it called from any other classes?

Comment: No it's just called from within the database class.

Comment: So i guess it doesn't need to be public lol.

Comment: It's good practice to make those types of methods, which are only used by the class, private.  Not necessary, but it can help prevent problems down the line.

Comment: Thanks Flynn you are spot on tbh, not sure why I did that.

Comment: @Flynn81 have you seen the new error that I've generated, not used sqlite before proving to be quite an issue, any ideas on the error? It must be something to do with me adding elements to the database as it repeats itself about 50 times...

Comment: Try changing "country name" to "country_name".  You may need to uninstall your app or clear it's data from the settings to see the change, not sure if your database was created or not (I'm leaning towards not).

Comment: @Flynn81, hi bud it now appears there is an error with the curser while it's reading the database:

Comment: @Flynn81 06-12 20:03:02.953: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Usually happens when the Cursor hasn't been set to a row in the result set.  If you are running a query and using a Cursor, that Cursor needs to be moved to a row. Try using Cursor.moveToFirst(), that should set the Cursor to the first row returned.  You can also check the total rows returned using Cursor.getCount().

Comment: Thanks @Flynn81, I have cursor.moveToNext() in a while loop (as above), I tried adding move to g=first above the while loop and it produces the same error but just moans about the second line instead of the first..

Comment: Is my query the issue?

Comment: No, issue is that index variable.  Each time you call Cursor.moveToNex() you are working with a new row, but each loop you increase index.  The method, Cursor.getString() takes an index relative to the number of columns in the projection, so you can just use 0 and 1 as the two values you pass, no need to increment a value for those methods.

Comment: Any luck? Got things working?

Comment: @Flynn81, thanks matey you've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Pass db as a parameter to populateTable() when calling that method from onCreate().  You already have the db open from onCreate(), no need to get a writable database again.

onCreate would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + COUNTRY + " TEXT," + INDICATOR + " TEXT,"
            + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT" + ")"; 

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    populateTable(db);
}
```

and start of populateTable() would look like this:

```
public void populateTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
    cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
    ...
}
```

For the second error, problem is probably your column names.  Try changing "Country name" to "country_name".  I think it's the space in the name that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the changes you made, it looks like you might need to take out the space in your COUNTRY variable.

Try using something like;

```
private static final String COUNTRY = "Country_Name";
```